# C++ Compilation error(gcc 4.7)

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, gcc4.7

I'm trying to do 11 exercise at the end of Chapter 5.9 Bjarne Stroustrup The C++ Programming Language.

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <string>
  3 #include <vector>
  4 #include <algorithm>
  5 
  6 void print(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator str) {
  7    std::cout << *str;
  8 }
  9 
 10 int main(void) {
 11    std::vector<std::string> words;
 12    std::string tmp;
 13 
 14    std::cin >> tmp;
 15    while (tmp != "Quit") {
 16       words.push_back(tmp);
 17       std::cin >> tmp;
 18    }
 19 
 20    for_each(words.begin(), words.end(), print);
 21 
 22    return 0;
 23 }
```

When I uncomment 20 line I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from 5.9.11.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >; _Funct = void (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >)]’:
5.9.11.cpp:20:44:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4442:2: error: could not convert ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >()’ from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’
```

Compile command :

```
g++ prog.cpp -o prog -Wall
```

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function should take an `std::string`, not an iterator. `for_each` passes each element itself. Thus, your function would become:

```
void print(const std::sting &str) {
    std::cout << str << ' '; //note I separated the words
}
```

For a fixed example (including the `std::` on `for_each`, as well as a couple other minor differences), see [this run](http://ideone.com/4MjDr).

In C++11 (accessible to your compiler through `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`), you need not even worry about `std::for_each` to loop through the container because C++11 introduced the ranged-for loop:

```
for (const std::string &str : words)
    std::cout << str << ' ';
```

Comment: +1 For the range based, haven't used it much as spend most of my time with VC2010 (which does not support it).

Comment: @hmjd, Yeah, I find that one of the most useful features of C++11, and have heard about it not being supported there :/

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris), the `print()` function should accept a `const std::string&`. As an alternative, you could use a lambda function:

```
std::for_each(words.begin(),
              words.end(),
              [](const std::string& a_s)
              {
                  std::cout << a_s << "\n";
              });
```

Add compiler flag `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Good suggestion, but if we're getting into C++11, the ranged-for would be my preferred choice. I guess I'll add that option to the list.

Comment: @chris, g++ v4.7 supports some C++11 features so why not?